# Can Rpi receive serial/UART data through GPIO pin?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio

Can I receive data which is transmitted through UART port from a transmitter side raspberry pi on a receiver side Raspberry pi's GPIO pin??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103562/discussion-on-question-by-kunal-can-rpi-receive-serial-uart-data-through-gpio-p).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as the signal is 3V3 compatible.

You could use the Pi's UART RX pin (pin 10, GPIO 15) and the standard Linux serial software.  That will handle standard baud rates (say up to 1 Mbps).

Alternatively you can use a general GPIO (any other GPIO on the extension header) and software serial.  That should be good up to 19k2 bps or so.

Comment: Thanks sir @joan. Can u please tell me that if I am receiving audio data then while receiving can I play that data at the same time

Comment: @kunal If you want to change your question you need to edit those changes into the question.